# Python function to find the Max of three numbers and compare number

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function works for finding maximum number. And I also need to compare numbers and show the number are same if the input is same numbers. As i have taken `a=2`, `b=8`, `c=8` three numbers the maximum is `8` and the program should also show that `b` and `c` are same.

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    if a>b and a>c :
        print("Biggest Number=",a)
    elif b>a and b>c:
        print("Biggest Number=",b)
    elif a==b:
        print("a=b") 
    elif a==c: 
         print("a=c")
    elif b==c:
        print("b=c")
    else:
        print("Biggest Number=",c)    
biggest(2,8,8)
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: here i get the result b=c only , Biggest number does not appear in output.

Comment: Remove `else` and unindent `print("Biggest Number=",c)`.

Comment: You need to get a bit of understanding of what an if statement does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lots of `if`/`elif`/`else` will lead to difficulties to read and maintain your code. I suggest you a better a solution, with comments in order you can understand it:

```
def biggest(a, b, c):
    # Define a dictionary d with strings 'a','b','c' as keys to associate with values
    d = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}
    # Find the maximum value
    maxValue = max(d.values())
    # Gather all keys corresponding to max value into list
    maxLetters = [k for k,v in d.items() if v == maxValue]
    # Format and print the result
    print("Biggest number is ", maxValue, " (", "=".join(maxLetters), ")", sep="")

biggest(1,2,3)  # Biggest number is 3 (c)
biggest(1,2,2)  # Biggest number is 2 (b=c)
biggest(2,2,2)  # Biggest number is 2 (a=b=c)
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using **args**. Args allows us to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.
e.g.

```
print( max( *[ 1, 10, 3] ) )
```

Useful links:-
1. http://thepythonguru.com/python-args-and-kwargs/

Comment: pretty sure there is no problem to solve. The user is new and didn't understand how if statements worked

Comment: My bad, I should have read the whole question. I thought he wanted a shortcut to find the max of 3 numbers.

Comment: All fair. It still helps a heck load for his situation. :)

Comment: I really can't understand why this answer has 4 upvotes, whereas it does not answer to the question at all... It seems quite unfair.

Comment: If you take a look, there isn't actually any clear problem statement. My answer only has one vote even though it's what he wanted. Others made suggestions to improve instead, which i do agree with. The problem isn't the answers it's the question; there isn't one though.

Comment: I may agree. But 4 upvotes for this post, it is really too much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with how your code works and how you've described it, simply change all the "elif" statements to new ifs. This makes it so you can check all conditions instead of having it abort as soon as it finds one it can resolve.

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
    if a>b and a>c :
        print("Biggest Number=",a)
    if b>a and b>c:
        print("Biggest Number=",b)
    if a==b:
        print("a=b") 
    if a==c: 
         print("a=c")
    if b==c:
        print("b=c")
    if a<b and a<c:
      print("Biggest Number=",c)  
biggest(8,1,1)
```

This could probably be done cleaner and better but that's your job in learning. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
def biggest(a,b,c):
if a>b and a>c :
    print("Biggest Number=",a)
elif b>a and b>c:
    print("Biggest Number=",b)
else:
    print("Biggest Number=",c)

if a==b:
        print("a=b") 

if a==c: 
        print("a=c")
if b==c:
        print("b=c")
if a==b==c:
    print("a=b=c")

biggest(2,5,8)
biggest(2,8,8)
biggest(8,8,8)
```

worked  for both comparing, maximum and equal number.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that - even if not stated clearly - the point of that question was to write a function in order to find the biggest of three numbers *without* using the max() built-in function. 
This can be done with:

```html
def biggest(x,y,z):
    if x>=y and x>=z:
        print(x)
    elif y>x and y>z:
        print(y)
    else:
        print(z)
```

Happy coding :)